# EnableLoadTimeWeaving did not weave other config in web application context

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, aspectj, spring-aop, load-time-weaving

I try to use spring weblogic LTW in my project to do some aop stuff. my project is a simple webapp servlet2.5 use spring mvc 3.2.6, running on weblogic 10.0.
I have following app level configuration setup in web.xml

> ```
> @Configuration
> @EnableLoadTimeWeaving
> public class AppConfig {
>
> }
>
>
> @Configuration
> @EnableTransactionManagement
> @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.blabla.model" })
> public class CoreConfig {
> }
> ```

I also have a mvc level configuration setup in my web.xml

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.blabla.controller" })
public class MVCConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
}
```

here is my simplified web.xml

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>AppConfig,CoreConfig
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>
                org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>MVCConfig
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>wl-dispatch-policy</param-name>
            <param-value>RestWorkManager</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

so what happens is, `MVCConfig` and its scanned components are all woven by LTW and works great. but `CoreConfig` and its scanned components (all the DAO) are **not** picked up by LTW.

I guess that the `CoreConfig` and `AppConfig` is in the same level, so when `AppConfig`  and `CoreConfig` are loaded, the LTW is not triggered yet.

And I tried to put the `CoreConfig` in the same level as `MVCConfig`, it got picked up by LTW.

but `CoreConfig` is supposed to be application level, not dispatchservlet level. Since many spring web MVC applications use a root context and a child for the DispatcherServlet.

so My question is if I put `CoreConfig` in the app level, how to make LTW pick it up? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Loadtimeweaving will only work for classes that aren't already loaded by the class loader.

Now when using XML configuration the actual bean classes are loaded after the load time weaving is enabled so it works, more or less, flawlessly for all classes.

With Java Config classes are loaded as soon as the `@Configuration` annotationed class is loaded. All classes that are imported are loaded into the class loader. After this load time weaving is enabled, however only for classes that are going to be loaded after this point.

Hence the fact that it is working for classes loaded by the configuration as specified for the `DispatcherServlet` and hence the problem in the `ContextLoaderListener`.

One thing you can try is to put a `@ComponentScan` for `@Configuration` classes on the `AppConfig`. And let the `ContextLoaderListener` only load the `AppConfig`. That might defer the class loading a little until after the load time weaving is enabled.

Something that definitely will work is putting both configuration classes in XML, remove the `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving` for the `AppConfig` and use a `<context:load-time-weaving />`.

Comment: nice answer, so there is no way to use javaConfig in this case? is it a problem with component scan? if I use component scan in xml, it will load the beans as well, right?

Comment: In general it has to do with the `import` statements. Next to the `@Configuration` classes are basically normal beans themselves which are pre-processed. Not sure if it is only related to `@ComponentScan`. One thing you could try is to create a custom subclass of `org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` which registers everything for load time weaving upon creation of the context (i.e. before anything is loaded). `@Configuration` classes and XML are processed quite differently.

Comment: can you shed some light on difference between @Configuration and XML processing?